# Jasmine toBeCloseTo what is second parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Jasmine has very short documentation; often it's enough. Not always.

I want to know what is exactly the second parameter of toBeCloseTo. Official reference only shows:

```
it("The 'toBeCloseTo' matcher is for precision math comparison", function() {
    var pi = 3.1415926, e = 2.78;
    expect(pi).not.toBeCloseTo(e, 2);
    expect(pi).toBeCloseTo(e, 0);
});
```

OK it is precision, but what practically means "precision" in this case? Is it the number of digits after the "." that should be the same?

My case: i want to compare two timestamps in milliseconds; if the difference between them is less than 100, it's fine for me.

As example, what's the value of X in the following case?

```
var timestamp1 = 1501254807000;
var timestamp2 = 1501254807099;
var timestamp3 = 1501254807100;
var precision = X;
expect(timestamp1).toBeCloseTo(timestamp2, precision); //this should pass
expect(timestamp1).toBeCloseTo(timestamp3, precision); //this should NOT pass
```

If the precision is only for decimal numbers, I could divide my integers by 1000 to get decimal numbers, but anyway, I don't know what is X.
For now, I do in this way:

```
 expect(Math.abs(timestamp2-timestamp1)).toBeLessThan(100);
```

but it's not very readable, and I would like to use toBeCloseTo (since it exests...).

Thanks

---

Edit. The following results may help:

```
expect(1000000.005).toBeCloseTo(1000000.000,3); //fails
expect(1000000.005).toBeCloseTo(1000000.000,2); //fails
expect(1000000.005).toBeCloseTo(1000000.000,1); //pass
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at [the source for the toBeCloseTo matcher](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/toBeCloseTo.js)?

Comment: The documentation says "The number of decimal points to check."

Comment: BTW i added a new examples, that seems to not be according documentation as reported by Nikolaj

Comment: Google brings me on: jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html - that has been the only documentation/reference of Jasmine I know :)
Anyway the example they give (and I copied in my question) is at least very strange. One could ask why, if precision is 2 the variables pi and e in the example are not close, and if the precision is 0 they are close.


@fatLewis Looking at the source code? Documentation should be well done, in order to don't require looking at source for such details, i think...

Comment: I would normally agree with respect to documentation, but the matcher code is very short (just under 40 lines) and has JSDoc tags. I'll write up an answer to this later, but @Nikolaj is correct.

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/main/src/core/matchers/toBeCloseTo.js

Comment: Also the test, they might explain stuff too: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/main/spec/core/matchers/toBeCloseToSpec.js

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As was stated by @Nikolaj, the "precision" parameter specifies the number of decimal places that the matcher will check precision at, with rounding.

For the examples that you've given, the first two assertions fail because, at 3 and 2 decimal places respectively, the numbers are found to be different (at 2 decimal places the trailing 05 becomes rounded to 1). At 1 decimal place the numbers are the same.

The matcher does accept a negative precision value, e.g.:

```
expect(1000).toBeCloseTo(1003,-1); //pass
expect(1000).toBeCloseTo(1100,-2); //fail
expect(1000).toBeCloseTo(1100,-3); //pass
```

But it's not very adjustable beyond that. Sadly this does mean that the matcher isn't suited for your purposes, so you're probably stuck with your suggested solution.

Comment: Detailed explanation, thanks.  But Jasmine would do better to not round each value before comparing, that basically forces user to specify one digit less precision.

Answer (score -3):

Here is an example from Jest documentation that helped me better understand value of `toBeCloseTo` matcher.

```
expect(0.1+0.2).toBe(0.3); // fails becouse it's 0.30000000000000004
expect(0.1+0.2).toBeCloseTo(0.3); // pass
```